# How does the Green-Flame Blade cantrip's damage stack with the Arcana cleric's Potent Spellcasting feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage, cleric, cantrips

I am aware from the Sage Advice that potent spellcasting adds damage to both the first and second enemy when using *green-flame blade*.

What I want to clarify is that this means that the second enemy takes my Wisdom modifier (I am playing an Arcana cleric) twice?

We are starting at level 11, so if this is the case then I would be dealing 5d8+18 for an average of 40 damage (I have a 20 Wis and a 16 Dex. I am using a rapier as my weapon) with a cantrip.

Is this high for a cantrip at this level or pretty average?

Comment: The first question seems like a duplicate of this one: [Do both targets of Green-Flame Blade (gained by the Arcana Domain) benefit from Potent Spellcasting?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77640/do-both-targets-of-green-flame-blade-gained-by-the-arcana-domain-benefit-from)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## The damage stacks

The secondary target takes your Wisdom modifier twice, as you wrote it yourself.

## Very good damage for a cantrip

Only Eldritch Blast can come close to the raw damage. Compared to weapon attacks, it is OK.
A Fighter with a Greatsword could inflict the same damage, but with a much better chance to hit, so a higher DPR.

Calculating full damage for the secondary target is misleading. Even if there *is* a second enemy in range, spreading damage is usually weaker than focusing it. For this reason I would calculate (as was accepted on the WotC forums while they existed) by halving the secondary damage.

## DPR calculation

At level 11 you can expect to fight against CR11 monsters; they are expected to have AC 17.

### Green-flame Blade + Potent Spellcasting

Hit chance: 55% (4+3 vs 17)
Damage: 31  \$=\left(8+4.5\times3+\frac{10+4.5\times2}{2}\right)\$
**DPR: 17.05**

### Great weapon Fighter

Hit chance: 65% (4+5 vs 17)
Damage: 40 \$=(3 \times (8.33+5))\$
**DPR: 26**

### Warlock with Agonizing Blast

Hit chance: 65% (4+5 vs 17)
Damage: 31.5 \$=(3 \times (5.5+5))\$
**DPR: 20.48**

I would highlight that the Warlock and the Figher can spread their damage among multiple targets *if they so wish*, but your Green Glame Blade has no such option.

## Conclusion

It is very good damage from a Cleric without spending spell slots, but not spectacular in itself.

Comment: Also note that it is across two targets. Everyone else can focus on a single target.

Comment: Also note warlock has hex which gives a 3d6 necrotic damage boost and lays forever

Comment: @NautArch it was already in there, but I highlighted it more

Comment: @GarretGang By spending spell slots, the Cleric can also improve his damage output, but I wanted to compare _free_ options

Comment: That's true, but hex lays for eight hours at 11th level,  none of the cleric spell boosters last as long. And for a blasting warlock you can assume they have hex up and running constantly.

Comment: @GarretGang You can have it up all day, you just have to ignore concentration, necrotic resistance, and better spells.

Comment: True, very true. Guess I am to used to Rangers who really don't get better damage concentration spells til much later.

Comment: A minor benefit for GFB is that the second target gets hit automatically, so you can (in *very specific* situations) circumvent high-AC opponents by hitting low-AC bystanders. Get yourself that *Bag of Rats* and hit every time.

Answer (score 14):

## Yes, Damage stacks

As you've stated, Potent Spellcasting states (SCAG, 126):

> Starting at 8th level, you add your Wisdom modifier to the damage you deal with any cleric cantrip.

And the Arcane Initiate ability stats (SCAG, 125):

> ...you gain two cantrips of your choice from the wizard spell list. For you,  these cantrips count as cleric cantrips.

This lets you combine them for the following damage:

- **Primary Target**: 1d8+3 Piercing plus 2d8+5 fire
- **Secondary Target**: 2d8+10 fire damage

[Jeremy Crawford's unofficial guidance on Twitter](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/756203803339173888) also concurs with this:

> Potent Spellcasting adds to dmg. dealt by a cantrip. GFB: add to 2nd target, then to both targets at 5th lvl

### Comparisons

Eldritch Blast with a Warlock can deliver up to 3d10+15 force damage per casting, for an average of 31.

Comment: Thank you! Can i just ask though, how am i supposed to know which type of damage to add the wisdom modifier too on the primary target?

Comment: The bonus is added to the fire damage, not the weapon damage. The fact that Crawford says "...then to both targets at 5th level" shows he doesn't consider the weapon damage part of the cantrip's damage. This is consistent with the spell's description saying it fails if you don't make a weapon attack. A bonus to damage uses the same damage  type as the damage it's being added to; it doesn't have to be the damage type of a weapon attack.

Comment: @Doval I think I agree with that. The Green-Flame is about the Flame and not really about the weapon attack. I'll adjust.

Comment: Warlock does a bit more than 31 damage,  add 3d6 from hex and possibly 3d8 from bestow curse and you do 59 damage power round. Against a single target.  Against multiple creatures work just hex,  you do 41.5 damage a round