# How do the Spirit Shroud and Green-Flame Blade spells interact?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage, attack

The description of the [*spirit shroud*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/spirit-shroud) spell says (emphasis mine):

> **any** attack you make deals 1d8 extra damage when you hit a creature within 10 feet of you.

The description of the [*green-flame blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/green-flame-blade) spell says (emphasis mine):

> On a hit, the target suffers the weapon attack’s normal effects, **and you can** cause green fire to leap from the target to a different creature of your choice that you can see within 5 feet of it.

To me, that sounds like the single attack from *green-flame blade* is damaging 2 creatures, and the extra damage from *spirit shroud* should apply to both creatures.

**Does the target of the secondary damage of *green-flame blade* also receive the extra damage from *spirit shroud*?**

Comment: Related: "[How does the Green-Flame Blade cantrip interact with the tiefling feat Flames of Phlegethos?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/176782)" and "[What is the interaction between Green-Flame Blade and Absorb elements](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/174094)" and "[Do both targets of Green-Flame Blade (gained by the Arcana Domain) benefit from Potent Spellcasting?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/77640)" and "[Does a Spores druid's extra damage from Symbiotic Entity apply to a creature hit by the secondary damage of Green-Flame Blade?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/153778)"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

RAW: no.

> "The second creature takes fire damage equal to your spellcasting ability modifier."

Spirit Shroud only takes effect on an attack, and as written the second creature "takes damage"; you do not explicitly make an attack against the second creature for the Spirit Shroud to affect.

Comment: Also, I would include the Spirit Shroud damage in "the attack's normal effects", which apply only to the creature you hit with the attack.